# how to add counter to a list using a for loop?

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop

i am writing a function that takes a dictionary, and for each key it puts the key and value in a list with a number representing the order. example, dictionary: {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}. the list should look like  this ["1) key1: value1", "2) key2: value2", "3) key3: value3"].

I am able to get it so that it puts all of the dictionary items in a list, but I cant get it so that the numbers appear. this is the code that I have written so far:

```
def listItems(index):
    things = []
    for x,y in index.items():
        things.append(str(x)+": "+str(y))
    return things
    
thisdict = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}

print(listItems(thisdict))
```

I have tried doing this for the numbers, but it does not work:

```
def listItems(index):
    things = []
    for x,y in index.items():
        for i in range(len(index))
            things.append(str(i)+") "+str(x)+": "+str(y))
    return things
    
thisdict = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: Return books ? Where did you create books?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **list comprehension** to create a list from the dictionary:

```
thisdict = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}

lst = [str(i+1) + ") " + k+ ":" + thisdict[k] for i,k in enumerate(thisdict)]

print(lst)
```

Output

```
['1) key1:value1', '2) key2:value2', '3) key3:value3']
```